# Extracting a range of data from a table

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have text file with data in 2 columns. 
I have imported it using the following line

```
c = Import["ab", "Table"];
```

This text file has a large amount of data, and I need only a certain range. 
What I mean is, if my data runs for example from `-10 to +10`, I need only from `-5 to +5` and its corresponding values.

So I naively tried this

```
Plot[c, {-5, 5}]
```

which is clearly wrong, and its little wonder that I am getting an error message.

Not sure what to do. Please help!

Comment: Hello, your approach is no so bad. But assuming this data is a coordinate list you have to use `ListPlot` and with given `PlotRange` it will work. However, it does not affect your data but only the plotted area.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! I tried this PlotRange -> { {-5, 5}, {-10, 10} } and it works. Turns out with the first set ie {-5, 5} I can manipulate the x axis,and with the second, the y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select` like this:

```
data = Table[{i, RandomReal[1]}, {i, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
filtered = Select[data, (.1 < #[[2]] < .5) &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[filtered, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
ListLinePlot[{data, filtered},PlotLegends -> {"original", "filtered"}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Nasser- Thanks..:)